# make vertical moving background

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, sprite-kit

I'm beginner in Spritekit and I try to make background move vertically
I did know how
this what in the controller

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
        let skView = view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
```

and this the scene

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

var background = SKSpriteNode()
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    let backgroundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bbbgg.png")

    let shiftBackground = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: -backgroundTexture.size().height, duration: 5)
    let replaceBackground = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y:backgroundTexture.size().height, duration: 0)
    let movingAndReplacingBackground = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([shiftBackground,replaceBackground]))

    for i in 1...3{
        background=SKSpriteNode(texture:backgroundTexture)
        background.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        background.size.height = self.frame.height
        background.run(movingAndReplacingBackground)

        self.addChild(background)
    }
}
```

}

the problem is the background move horizontally and after it arrives to the end of screen disappear, then begins move from the beginning of the screen again

[image]

I want it work vertically without disappearing

Answer (score 0):

The background move horizontally because declarations of moveBy (shiftBackground, replaceBackground) works on the x axe (horizontally). You need to work on the y axe (vertically).

```
    let shiftBackground = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: -backgroundTexture.size().height, duration: 5)
    let replaceBackground = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: backgroundTexture.size().height, duration: 0)
```

At the first line, the background move from it position to it position - it height. At the second line, it return to it first position (I think moveBy is relative).

_

The background move again because you use the function SKAction.repeatForever (movingAndReplacingBackground). I think you can remove it.

```
    let movingAndReplacingBackground = SKAction.sequence([shiftBackground,replaceBackground])
```

---

Edit :

I forget the loop.

In the loop, you give to the background an initial position.

```
            background.position = CGPoint(x: backgroundTexture.size().width/2 + (backgroundTexture.size().width * CGFloat(i)), y: self.frame.midY)
```

Try to replace it by 0, middle if you want an immediately visible background

```
        background.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.midY)
```

Or -height, 0 if you want the background appear by the top of the screen. In this case you need to replace shiftBackground and replaceBackground

```
        background.position = CGPoint(x: -backgroundTexture.size().height, y: 0)

    and

    let shiftBackground = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: backgroundTexture.size().height, duration: 5)

    let replaceBackground = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 0, duration: 0)
```

---

I'm not sure, but I think, if you want only one mouvement, you can remove th sequence :

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    var background = SKSpriteNode()
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        let backgroundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bbbgg.png")

        let scrollByTopBackground = SKAction.moveBy(x: O, y: backgroundTexture.size().height, duration: 5)

        background = SKSpriteNode(texture:backgroundTexture)
        background.position = CGPoint(x: -backgroundTexture.size().height, y: self.frame.midY)
        background.size.height = self.frame.height
        background.run(scrollByTopBackground)

        self.addChild(background)
    }
}
```

---

Edit to answer you, try this...

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

var background = SKSpriteNode()
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    let backgroundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bbbgg.png")

    let shiftBackground = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: -backgroundTexture.size().height, duration: 5)
    let replaceBackground = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y:backgroundTexture.size().height, duration: 0)
    let movingAndReplacingBackground = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([shiftBackground,replaceBackground]))

    for i in 0...2 {
        background=SKSpriteNode(texture:backgroundTexture)
        background.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.midY + (backgroundTexture.size().height * CGFloat(i)))
        background.size.height = self.frame.height
        background.run(movingAndReplacingBackground)

        self.addChild(background)
    }
}
```

Comment: I did these changes but nothing appear now, also I want in the first the background to be exist when I run the application, after that the movement begin

Comment: No I want the movement repeat forever for  that I use `repeatForever` I update my code after your comment, problem now: it's move from top to bottom but it start the movement from the middle of screen not from the top, also I think the app stop for few second between the movement, why?

Comment: the one in the question

Comment: In your first answer you have this one
            background.position = CGPoint(x: backgroundTexture.size().width/2 + (backgroundTexture.size().width * CGFloat(i)), y: self.frame.midY)

Now you have
            background.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

We can try to mix 
            background.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.midY)

Comment: Thx, that works! But I still see the blank between every movement, that take few second before the next background appear, I want the next background appear immediately after the old one disappear without see any space or blank between them, is it possible?

Comment: If you want use multiple background, you need to place it like this

    for i in 0...2{
        ....
        background.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.midY + (backgroundTexture.size().height * CGFloat(i)))
        ....
    }

The firt iteration (i == 0) : CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.midY)
The second iteration (i == 1) : CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.midY + (backgroundTexture.size().height))
The third iteration (i == 2) : CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.midY + (backgroundTexture.size().height * 2))

Comment: Sorry I confused about your answer, I added three iterations, but I couldn't know where I should write this `background.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.midY + (backgroundTexture.size().height * CGFloat(i)))` I tried to write it above and after the iterations, but doesn't help, neither without it

Comment: I have updated my answer. Did you understand principe of loop ?